# Running Cucumber tests with Junit Categories via Maven

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a maven project with multiple modules and one common parent module. In this project there are some unit tests run with Junit together with surefire, as well as BDD Cucumber integration tests. I would like to run two separate jobs, one to run all the unit tests, and one for running the BDD/Integration tests. In order to do that, I have annotated my BDD runner classes with a Junit category annotation like so:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
                tags = { "@ATagToBeRun", "~@ATagNotToBeRun","~@ToBeImplemented" },
                dryRun = false, strict = true, 
                features = "src/test/resources/cucumber/testing",
                glue = { "com.some.company.test",
                        "com.some.company.another.test"})
@Category(value = IntegrationTest.class)
public class FlowExecutionPojoTest {
}
```

I created a Maven profile in the parent `pom` which uses the `maven-surefire-plugin` feature that is intended to filter tests base on groups. Here is my maven configuration:

```
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profile>
        <id>testJewels</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>../my-module</module>
        </modules>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <groups>com.some.company.IntegrationTest</groups>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

What I expected was that when I run `mvn test -PtestJewels` the classes annotated with the category contained in the `<groups>` tag should be executed. In actuality none of the annotated classes executed.

An interesting point to note is that when I used the `maven-surefire-plugin` version 2.18 this worked, but from version 2.18.1 and on it did not. According to the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html) at the bottom of the page, there was a change in version 2.18.1 regarding categories being inherited but in my case they are being in

Comment: Can you share your pom dependencies? Did you include cucumber-java, cucumber-junit packages?

Comment: @eg04lt3r sure thing, added it to the question

Answer (score 4):

I discovered that there is actually a [pull request](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/1021) on the `cucumber-jvm` repository to fix this specific problem. The problem is caused as a result of the fact that when Junit filters the test runner classes based on the `@Category` annotation, it also checks all the child classes as well. In the case of a cucumber test that runs `.feature` files, all the classes that represent the `.feature` files are checked as well (cucumber converts each `.feature` file in an instance of the `FeatureRunner` class). Being that the annotation does not exist on the `FeatureRunner` class, the tests are filtered out and not run. (Prior to version 2.18.1 the `maven-surefire-plugin` did not check child classes for annotations and hence this was not a problem.

A workaround that works for the specific setup that I described above, where all the BDD tests are run in a specific module, was to override the `<groups>` configuration in the child module, like so:

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <groups combine.self="override"></groups>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This will obviously not work in a different setup, and it is therefore rather unfortunate that the cucumber team has yet to merge the PR that I mentioned above.